# Get value from the input field and use it as a parameter in the function

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a problem so I would value input from the input field as a parameter to put the delete function (insert in place X)

```
<input id="a" type="number" name="fname"><br>
<form action='#close' ng-controller='NoteFormController as formCtrl' ng-submit='formCtrl.delete(calCtrl.series[$index], X)'>
    <div class='form-field'>
        <input type='submit' value='delete value'>
    </div>
</form>
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: use `document.getElementById("a").value` instead of X

Comment: doesn't work, when getting value from this function is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You typically would need to use [`ngModel`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) directive to bind value from input element to scope model. For example:

```
<input id="a" type="number" name="fname" ng-model="fname">
<br>
<form action='#close' 
      ng-controller='NoteFormController as formCtrl' 
      ng-submit='formCtrl.delete(calCtrl.series[$index], fname)'>
    <div class='form-field'>
        <input type='submit' value='delete value' />
    </div>
</form>
```

Note, above snippet assumes that you have outer controller that wraps input and form, so that `fname` model will be set in the parent scope relative to `NoteFormController` scope.

Answer (score 0):

try this ....

```
 $('#a').value();
```

Comment: A series of confusing the document element :/

Answer (score 0):

Don't fallback to jQuery accessors. You should bind a scope variable to the input and access in the delete function or pass into the delete function.

```
<input id="a" type="number" name="fname" ng-model="someVariable"><br>
  <form action='#close' ng-controller='NoteFormController as formCtrl' ng-submit='formCtrl.delete(calCtrl.series[$index], someVariable)'>
        <div class='form-field'>
            <input type='submit' value='delete value'> 
        </div>
```

in your formCtrl controller, declare:

```
$scope.someVariable = '';
```

You can also access $scope.someVariable in the delete() function in the controller:

```
$scope.delete = function (seriesValue) {
    ...= $scope.someVariable;
}
```